# How to ignore extra params while creating model record in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

```
#Creating Products
class CreateProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :products do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :sku_id
      t.integer :price
      t.text :description
      t.datetime :expire_date
      t.boolean :admin_approved

      t.timestamps null: false
      t.index :sku_id
    end
  end
end

# Class for Products
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tags
  has_many :images
  has_and_belongs_to_many :categories,
   :join_table => :products_categories_mapping
  has_and_belongs_to_many :tags,
   :join_table => :products_tags_mapping
  validates :sku_id, :uniqueness => { "case_sensitive" => false }
  validates :name, presence: true
end
```

From the console, I am trying `Product.create(params)` and getting the following error with `params = {:name=>"XYZ", :sku_id=>"XXX", :source=>"API"}`

```
ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute 'source' for Product.
```

Comment: If you are trying from console, then why are giving `source` attribute ? Your model don't have that. If you need from controller then check Rails guide on strong parameter.

Comment: What happens if you try without the `source` parameter? Do you need it anyway? Sajan suggests the strong parameters API: It allows to filter parameters, and is perhaps the answer to your problem.

Comment: Worked with strong params

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to do so, first you can use attr_accessor within model like:

```
attr_accessor :source
```

Secondly you can filter params like:

```
Product.create(params.except(:source,:xyz))
```